# Changing data source of table using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, .net

Cross post from: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/125010

Does anyone know how to change the data source of a table using arcobjects? I know it can be done with arcpy, but I'm using C#. I've managed to change the source of all the layers in the mxd, but I need to do tables too.

---

I've come up with a solution by adding and removing from the table collection.

Is this the best way to do it?

```
        IMap map = ...;
        IWorkspace = ...;

        ITableCollection tableCollection = (ITableCollection)map;
        int tableCount = tableCollection.TableCount;

        // iterate over a copy of the tables so we can add and remove
        List<ITable> tables = new List<ITable>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tableCount; i++)
        {
            tables.Add(tableCollection.get_Table(i));
        }

        foreach (ITable oldTable in tables)
        {
            IDataset dataset = (IDataset)oldTable;
            IDatasetName datasetName = (IDatasetName)dataset.FullName;
            string workspaceName = datasetName.WorkspaceName.PathName;

            // get the new table
            ITable newTable = ((IFeatureWorkspace)workspace).OpenTable(datasetName.Name);

            // replace the table in the TOC
            tableCollection.RemoveTable(oldTable);
            tableCollection.AddTable(newTable);

            // fire change event to change table
            IMapAdmin2 mapAdmin2 = (IMapAdmin2)map;
            mapAdmin2.FireChangeTable(oldTable, newTable);
        }
```

Note: this is simplified - I did check the table was in the new workspace before opening it.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by changing the data source of a table.

Comment: I've copied the table to another database and want to update all my mxds. I'm looking for something like this snippet but for tables instead of feature layers http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000002r000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the table property of IStandaloneTable to change its datasource. First create a reference to the new ITable (e.g. a table from a geodatabase), then use this code to replace the Table property:

```
            IMap map = ...;
            IStandaloneTableCollection tbcol= (IStandaloneTableCollection)map;

            for (int i = 0; i < tbcol.StandaloneTableCount; i++)
            {
                var stTable = tbcol.get_StandaloneTable(i);
                stTable.Table = newTable; //Here put the new ITable  To change the datasource
                    if (!stTable.Valid)
                        MessageBox.Show("Table is not valid, "+stTable.Name);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Farid - I came up with a solution using ITableCollection (see edit). Is there a reason for using IStandaloneTableCollection instead?

Comment: I don't see any differences here. But IStandaloneTableCollection is implemented with NALayer (esriNetworkAnalyst) class too. Meaning this is more complete that ITableCollection