# Facing null ITable with ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, data-source

Recently this community helped me to get a list of the tables from an MXD file:

```
IMapDocument mapDoc = new MapDocument();
mapDoc.Open("C://mymxd.mxd");

IActiveView act = mapDoc.ActiveView;
IMap map = act.FocusMap;

IStandaloneTableCollection coleccionTablas = (IStandaloneTableCollection)map;

for (int i = 0; i < coleccionTablas.StandaloneTableCount; i++)
{
    IStandaloneTable stTable = coleccionTablas.get_StandaloneTable(i);
    string nameTOC = stTable.Name;
}
```

That way I get the name of the table as shown in the "Table of Contents" of ArcMap. I thought that from there, it would be easy to get the name of the table as stored in the database. In other words: I need the datasource of the table.

I found this code: [Changing data source of table using ArcObjects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138724)

That same solution is the only one I have found so far in different sites. It seems pretty easy, but I only get `ITable` objects that are null... so getting the datasource for those is impossible.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coleccionTablas.StandaloneTableCount; i++)
{
    IStandaloneTable stTable = coleccionTablas.get_StandaloneTable(i);
    string nameTOC = stTable.Name;

    ITable table = stTable.Table; //--> table is always null!!
    IDataset dataset = (IDataset)table;
    IDatasetName datasetName = (IDatasetName)dataset.FullName;
}
```

I have tested several MXD files with tables, but the `ITable` object I get from the `IStandaloneTable` is always null and I have no idea why.

I have also tried with `ITableCollection`, but the result is the same.

Does anyone know why I keep getting nulls? Maybe there is something horribly wrong with my code.

Comment: When you set `nameTOC` is that actually setting to the name of the table in TOC? Also your first bit of code is accessing a MapDocument object, are you actually wanting to get the tables in the _currently_ opened document, in that case you want to be accessing the map from mxdocument.

Comment: Strange ... did you try casting `stTable` to `IDataLayer2` then calling `IDataLayer2.Connect` ?  (Maybe for performance MapDocument does lazy loading of standalone tables since MapControl can't display them anyway).

Comment: Also, you can try casting `datasetName` to `IName` and then call `IName.Open()`, which should return an object that you can cast to `ITable`.

Comment: Is your table valid? (stTable.Valid)

Comment: @MichaelStimson if the datasource is not broken, yes the table is valid. With broken datasources I get a false value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to your comments, I've been able to get the datasource of my tables.

This morning I have realized my code had been tested against tables with a broken datasource. I have created an MXD with a table without a broken datasource and the code I posted in my question works without any problem.

But I also need to get the datasource of a table if it's broken. As suggested, I've tried to cast it to `IDataLayer2`, but I haven't been able to get the datasource (I guess I'm doing something wrong).

Instead of casting it to `IDataLayer2`, I have casted it to `IDataLayer`.

```
IStandaloneTable stTable = coleccionTablas.get_StandaloneTable(i);

var dataLayer = (IDataLayer)stTable;
var datasetName = (IDatasetName)dataLayer.DataSourceName;
string name = datasetName.Name;
```

That works for broken and unbroken datasources.